# Is it possible to extract the value of a ValueKey in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Column containing a series of containers, each of which has assigned a `key` of `ValueKey(integer)`.   The integer changes depending on a preassigned ID# for each item int he column

Now I need to know which of those containers is being viewed, so I can get a hold of the key for the container on the screen.  However, when I try to `debugPrint(mykey.key.toString());` I get a result of `[<28935522>]`, meaning my integer that I assigned to the ValueKey is now surrounded by `[<`.

I could try to regex the integer from `[<28935522>]`, but it seems silly to do that extra work, is there a way to directly extract the `ValueKey` value?

Comment: Just don't use `toString`?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore I need the `int`, if I don't convert it then its a `key` type

Comment: how about mykey.key.value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `value` property as shown in the documentation. [Documentation for `ValueKey.value`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueKey/value.html)

```dart
mykey.key.value;
```